# Receiving 'Invalid Use of Property' error when returning a data type from a function in VBA Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a function that attempts to return a `SubForm` data type. This function is used by various parent `Forms`.

The function looks like this:

```
Public Function mySubFrm(name As String, subformName As String) As SubForm

    Dim frm As Form
    Dim subFrm As SubForm

    Set frm = Forms(name)
    Set subFrm = frm.Controls(subformName)

    mySubFrm = subFrm

End Function
```

I've attempted to use it by the following:

```
Dim testSubForm As SubForm

testSubForm = mySubFrm("testForm", "testSubForm")
```

Immediately, it follows with compile error:

> Invalid use of property

What I've attempted to do was add a watch at `frm.Controls(subformName)` and I see its return type is `SubForm/SubForm`, so I feel as though I am declaring and setting the right data type, but then again I'm not sure?

Can someone assist me with what I'm not doing properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive the error because you're trying to set an object, but are not using the `Set` keyword.

Perhaps it should be the following:

```
Set mySubFrm = subFrm
```

Or

```
Set mySubFrm = frmDatasheet
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I did attempt to perform `Set mySubFrm = subFrm` but that also resulted in the same error

Comment: Then provide the code for that attempt, since that shouldn't generate this error.

Comment: @Pangu see my answer for the full explanation. Erik's answer is correct.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth `Set mySubFrm = subFrm` alone as mentioned did result in the same compile error, but I also had to perform `Set testSubForm = mySubFrm("testForm", "testSubForm")`, your answer pointed me in the right direction..upvoted and marked

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much Access, but I know VBA pretty well.

Your function is returning an object reference:

> ```
> Public Function mySubFrm(name As String, subformName As String) As SubForm
> ```

As such, its return value **must** be assigned using the `Set` keyword:

```
Set mySubFrm = subFrm
```

The reason why you're getting this confusing error, is because of a lovely (not!) thing in VBA called *default properties*.

See, a form has a *default property*, most likely its `Controls` collection - and that property is only exposing a `Public Property Get` accessor, which makes it read-only.

So when you omit the `Set` keyword:

```
mySubFrm = subFrm
```

VBA assumes the code is legal, and so the only thing you could possibly be wanting to do, is to assign that default property - in other words, it's behaving exactly as if you would have written:

```
mySubFrm.Controls = subFrm
```

But the `Controls` class' own default property is its `Item` member, which is also read-only: there's no way the default `Controls` property can appear on the left-hand side of an assignment.

Hence, *invalid use of property*.

My open-source project [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) will soon have an inspection that will issue a result whenever you're implicitly referring to an object's default property, offering to make the call explicit. Writing code that *says what it does, and does what it says* is hard when you don't even know you're referring to a default property.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, Erik did point me in the right direction but voted yours also for the clear explanation

Comment: @Pangu my pleasure. VBA compile errors are easily confusing, with all the implicit voodoo constantly happening. You can find a type's default property in the object browser (F2) - it's the property with the little blue dot (in some cases it's a hidden member!).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a different approach. Typically when you create a form with a subform, it's quite rare that you actually need the subform to be dynamic. There is almost always a relationship between the parent form and the child form, and I would consider a parent form without its child a broken object in general.

Therefore, when I need to access things that's on the subform, I prefer to use the explicit version:

```
Dim mySubForm As Access.SubForm
Set mySubForm = Me.Controls("mySubForm").Form

mySubForm.SomeControlOnMySubForm.Value = 123
```

Yes it's 3 lines now but the advantage is that the reference to a *specific* form is now made explicit in your parent form. You now can see from the code that the parent form *depends* on *that* subform. More importantly, if you delete or rename the control `SomeControlOnMySubform`, the above form will allow the VBA compiler to warn you that there is no such object on the subform, enabling you to verify your code.

In other words, try your best to convert any potential runtime errors into compile-time errors because compile-time errors are much easier to validate and prevent than runtime errors.

The same principle works in the reverse; when you want to describe your subform as explicitly depending on a parent form, you can do:

```
Dim myParent As Form_frmParent
Set myParent = Me.Parent
```

NOTE: The code all assumes that there are code-behinds for all forms involved. If a form has no code-behind, it won't have a VBA class for you to reference. In such case, I set the form's property `HasModule` (located in the `Others` tab) to `Yes` even if there's ultimately no code-behind. (The reason is that it used to be that you could create "lightweight" form by creating it with no code-behind but with modern hardware, there is hardly any difference)